# if statement including raw_input just prints whatever i type in to the keyboard

Tags: python, raw-input

I am very new to python and programming in general and I want to print out the string "forward" whenever i press "w" on the keyboard. It is a test which I will transform into a remote control for a motorized vehicle.

```
while True:
    if raw_input("") == "w":
        print "forward"
```

Why does it just print out every key I type?

Comment: The indentation is wrong, but if you indent before the second line and again on the third line, it should work.

Comment: I acctualy indented the if statement in my code. I dont know why it doesnt appear like that in the code block. If I do it otherwise I get an indentation error anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python 2.x the raw_input function will display all characters pressed, and return upon receiving a newline. If you want different behaviour you'll have to use a different function. Here's a portable version of getch for Python, it will return every key press:

```
# Copied from: stackoverflow.com/questions/510357/python-read-a-single-character-from-the-user
def _find_getch():
    try:
        import termios
    except ImportError:
        # Non-POSIX. Return msvcrt's (Windows') getch.
        import msvcrt
        return msvcrt.getch

    # POSIX system. Create and return a getch that manipulates the tty.
    import sys, tty
    def _getch():
        fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
        old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
        try:
            tty.setraw(fd)
            ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
        finally:
            termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, old_settings)
        return ch

    return _getch

getch = _find_getch()
```

It can be used like so:

```
while True:
    if getch() == "w":
        print "forward"
```

Answer (score 1):

`raw_input` reads an entire line of input. The line you're inputting is made visible to you, and you can do things like type some text:

```
aiplanes
```

go left a few characters to fix your typo:

```
airplanes
```

go back to the end and delete a character because you didn't mean to make it plural:

```
airplane
```

and then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and `raw_input` will return `"airplane"`. It doesn't just return immediately when you hit a keyboard key.

---

If you *want* to read individual keys, you'll need to use lower-level terminal control routines to take input. On Unix, the [`curses`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html) module would be an appropriate tool; I'm not sure what you'd use on Windows. I haven't done this before, but on Unix, I think you'd need to set the terminal to raw or cbreak mode and take input with `window.getkey()` or `window.getch()`. You might also have to turn off echoing with `curses.noecho()`; I'm not sure whether that's included in raw/cbreak mode.